# LinkButton in repeater does not postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a listing service I just hosted: www.listeratti.com; on my testing server it works (local), but on the live server the linkbuttons on the repeaters on the home page do not work? I do not know if its a framework issue or my code; can someone please look at the source for the page and guide me. Clicking a category on the homepage does not fire the events.

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("Category1", "~/ListResults.aspx?ID={0}") %>' CssClass="inrepeater" ValidateRequestMode="Inherit"><%# Eval("Category1") %></asp:LinkButton>
```

On the codebehind I'm binding data as such:

```
Repeater18.DataSource = dcv.Categories1.Where(x => x.ParentCategory == hdr.Header17).ToList();
            Repeater18.DataBind();
```

But if you click these; there's no event. Thanks in advance.

IE throws the problem as: WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions' is undefined. How do I get around this?

Comment: Is there any validation on the page?

Comment: Thats what Im totally lost about... how do I get to know if there's validation?

Comment: Building on top of @Adnrei comment - can you add attribute CausesValidation="false" to linkbutton and see how it goes ?

Comment: @user2363977, well, if you have put any validators on the page - then there is a validation there. Try what Ondrej suggested if you are not sure. If it works - then there was a validation which prevented the postback

Comment: ok, let me set that to false and see how it goes... thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks all for the help so far; I have set the validation to false; still the link buttons dont fire...

Comment: Is the postback URL rendered as expected in the actual HTML?

Comment: Hello Stilgar; it was perfect before but moving the solution online, I experienced this.

Comment: I do not know if I should remove "ValidateRequestMode"? or disable it.

Comment: Here's the actual problem as IE was able to throw: WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions' is undefined. Its something to do with Javascript; can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a bunch to everyone who directed me; I discovered the problem was some js files in the master pages were missing; the references in the header section which are usually added by VS, for some reason, the js files were not in the site's folder; I have uploaded them and the clicks now work; I will reload the site and see how it goes. For anyone having this issue, simply start a new project; copy the files and WebForms folder from the Scripts folder and replace in your project; the script references will normalize and all will be well.